# how 'negative sampling' improve word representation quality in word2vec?

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, deep-learning, word2vec, embedding

negative sampling in '**word2vec**' improves the training speed, that's obviously!

but why '**makes the word representations significantly more accurate.**'?

I didn't find the relevant discussion or details. can u help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to describe what the author of that claim may have meant, without the full context of where it appeared. For example, word-vectors can be optimized for different tasks, and the same options that make word-vectors better for one task might make them worse for another.

One popular way to evaluate word-vectors since Google's original paper & code release is a set of word-analogy problems. These give a nice repeatable summary 'accuracy' percentage, so the author might have meant that for a particular training corpus, on that particular problem, holding other things constant, the negative-sampling mode had a higher 'accuracy' score.

But that wouldn't mean it's always better, with any corpus, or for any other downstream evaluation of quality or accuracy-on-some-task.

Projects with larger corpuses, and especially larger vocabularies (more unique words), tend to prefer the negative-sampling mode. The hierarchical-softmax alternative mode becomes slower as the vocabulary becomes larger, while the negative-sampling mode does not.

And, having a large, diverse corpus, with many subtly-different usage examples of all interesting words, is the most important contributor to really good word-vectors.

So, simply by making larger corpuses manageable, within a limited amount of training time, negative-sampling could be seen as indirectly enabling improved word-vectors - because corpus size is such an important factor.